# Can a character without a skill use a card that adds to that skill?

Tags: pathfinder-adventure

I'm playing Seoni who has a d4 for Strength and no Melee skill. If I want to resolve a combat check with my strength can I play a Soldier card which adds 1d4 to a Melee combat check if I don't have the Melee skill? Are my normal attacks, by default, Melee?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading some other forums, I believe the answer is actually **Yes**

Note: someone of the below is copied from David C Ellis's answer.

From the [Paizo FAQ's Attempting a Check section](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1gk#v5748eaic9ram):

> Cards that require a check specify the skill or skills you can use to attempt the check. Each check to defeat or acquire a card lists one or more skills; you may choose any of the listed skills for your check. For example, if a check lists Dexterity, Disable, Strength, and Melee, you may use any one of those skills to attempt your check.

and

> Even if your character doesn’t have any of the skills listed for a check, you can still attempt the check (unless you’re trying to recharge a card; see Recharge on page 15), but your die is a d4.
>
> (Recharge on page 15 reads:)if you don't have at least one of the skills listed for the check, you cannot attempt to recharge the card

and

> Players may not play cards that modify a skill unless you’re using that skill, and players may not play cards that affect combat unless you’re attempting a combat check.

So based on the first and second quote, you have to choose one of the skills listed on the card you're attempting to acquire/defeat/etc. even if you don't have that skill on your character card, but your die will be a d4. The wording "*Even if* your character doesn’t have any of the skills" simply suggests an extreme case, it doesn't mean that's the only situation where you can use a d4. It implies that you may use a d4 for a skill check with a skill you *don't* have, even if there are other skills (that you *do* have) to choose from. The only exception is recharging. In that case, you must recharge using one of the skills that you do have.

Then, based on the third quote, you can only play cards that modify the skill you chose so if you chose melee (even though it's not on your character card), you may use an ally that modifies your melee check. This third quote just states that you may not use an ally that, say, adds a die to your intelligence check if you chose melee as your check attempt skill.

Answer (score 2):

**Unfortunately, No.**

From the [Paizo FAQ's Attempting a Check section](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1gk#v5748eaic9ram):

> Cards that require a check specify the skill or skills you can use to attempt the check. Each check to defeat or acquire a card lists one or more skills; you may choose any of the listed skills for your check. For example, if a check lists Dexterity, Disable, Strength, and Melee, you may use any one of those skills to attempt your check.

Also:

> Players may not play cards that modify a skill unless you’re using that skill, and players may not play cards that affect combat unless you’re attempting a combat check.

So based on the first part, you have to choose one of the listed skills for your check, and if you do not have the skill, you cannot choose it. Then, based on the second part, you can only play cards that modify the skill you chose.

So since your character does not have the Melee skill, you cannot choose to use it to resolve the check, so therefore you cannot use the Soldier to add to the check.

Comment: actually i've been reading through other forums and also the 
FAQ you posted and you CAN use an ally to assist you on a check where you don't have the skill. you simply roll and a d4 + your ally's die. in your answer it even says "you may choose any of the listed skills for your check". that's referring to the card you're trying to acquire/defeat, _not_ your character card. otherwise why would seoni's starting deck contain all these allies that help her with various check if she can't even perform those checks?

Comment: @mikelt21 I've just seen the edit you suggested for this answer. Completely modifying an answer to the point the entire meaning changes is far beyond [what editing is for](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) - if there's another stance you think is correct, write your own answer for this question and accept it.

Comment: gotcha thanks for the info. is there a way to delete the edit?